# How to shutdown outlook programatically Outlook in a 2010 AddIn Project?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, shutdown

I need to close outlook when time is 00:00 every day.Is there any method that closes outlook programatically?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enjoy!

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(p =>
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime endOfDay = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
                TimeSpan timeLeftForClose = endOfDay.Subtract(now);
                Thread.Sleep(timeLeftForClose);
                this.Application.Quit();                    
            });
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }


        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }


    }
```

Comment: This works for me!Extra thanks for timer operations.Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

```
Outlook.Application OutlookApp;
OutlookApp = (Outlook.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
OutlookApp.Quit()
```